# Generating and sorting a sequence of 20 numbers in an array w/ for loop (Java)

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble in generating and sorting a sequence of 20 random numbers in an array with a for loop in java. It runs, but doesn't generate the proper output. The math.random import isn't being used, as per netbeans and I'm not sure why, as I do call it. I've been working on it for a couple hours to no avail.

```java
package problem1;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class problem1
{
public static void main(String[] args)

{   num num = new num();
    int[] array = new int[20];

    printSequence(array);
}
private static void printSequence(int[] num)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    int RandomNum = num[i];
    RandomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 99 + 1);

System.out.println("The sequence is: ");
printSequence(RandomNum);
}
}

private static printOrderedSequence(int[] array)
{
  Arrays.sort(array);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
System.out.println("The sequence in order is: ");
Arrays.toString(array);
}
}
```

Comment: consider your logic again within your first for loop.

Comment: There is no `math.random` import; *`java.util.Random`* isn't being used, because you're not using the `Random` class in this code. You don't have to import `java.util.Random` if you don't want to use it.

Comment: And the array isn't being printed because `Arrays.toString(array)` isn't part of a call to `System.out.println(...)`: it's just a method call in its own statement.

Comment: What do you think `num num = new num();` does?

Comment: @AndyTurner apologise, my bad.

Comment: @AndyTurner, I should've been more specific. I need to use 20 values between 0-99, randomize them, then sort them. Num creates the variable but doesn't initialize it to anything (doing that caused issues when executing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already import `java.util.Arrays` why not use that to print out the sequence?

*Note: I removed the unnecessary import of `java.util.Random` (you can use revert back to using that if you want, and whatever `num` was for as I think that made everything more complicated than required.*

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class problem1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] sequence = new int[20];

    //Generates 20 Random Numbers in the range 1 to 99
    for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length; i++)
      sequence[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 99 + 1);

    System.out.println("The sequence is: " + Arrays.toString(sequence));

    //Sort the sequence
    Arrays.sort(sequence);

    System.out.println("The sorted sequence is: " + Arrays.toString(sequence));
  }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
The sequence is: [10, 25, 94, 61, 59, 14, 64, 90, 28, 54, 29, 17, 71, 74, 95, 9, 56, 46, 44, 57]
The sorted sequence is: [9, 10, 14, 17, 25, 28, 29, 44, 46, 54, 56, 57, 59, 61, 64, 71, 74, 90, 94, 95]
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/GIKj/0)

Comment: Thank you for that, but a couple questions. Everything I've previously read online said a second for loop was required for sorting the array (as I've done in its own private class). Is this redundant? Secondly, how are the numbers randomly generated with math.random without the import?

Comment: Sorting the array is done using `Arrays.sort` (you were doing this before) if you need to implement a sort from scratch look at this. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms. Secondly you do not need to import `Math` specifically in java, and using `Math.random` is one of the more easier ways to generate random numbers in Java for beginners in my opinion.